# Change fonts in assets directory in android Widget

Tags: android

Due to widget development there is a requrement in definition of my own font (wich can be changed sometimes via SharedProperties).

One fo the soultion i saw here is to use:

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yearthree_view);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/Century_Gothic.ttf"); 
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

But the problem is: onUpdate() method dosn't familiar with

> findViewById

My approach using  RemoteViews  to get to TextView in order to update text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom TextView extends TextView and set the Typeface when initialize.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            initTextFont(context);
        }

        public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            initTextFont(context);
        }

        private void initTextFont(Context context) {
            //Set font here.
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `context.getassets() ;`
context is passed in onUpdate

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Century_Gothic.ttf");
```